# Vim Command Mapping "Copy to Clipboard" Not Working

Tags: bash, vim

I recently began using Vim as my primary editor instead of programs like Atom/VSCode. I added a number of leader mappings to simplify tasks I do quite often but I'm having trouble with a few of them.

In Visual mode, I would like to be able to press `<Space>y` to copy the current selection to the clipboard (`+ register`). I've verified that I can do this manually by entering visual mode, selecting the text I want, and pressing `"+y`. However, my mapping doesn't seem to work:
`vmap <Leader>y "+y`

I set my leader the following way:
`map <Space> <Leader>`

I do it this way so that when `showcmd` is set, I get a visual indicator in operator-pending mode. By looking at that indicator, I can tell that when I press `<Space>`, I do enter operator pending mode on the `\` key as expected. Then, when I press `y`, I am no longer in operator pending mode, but I am still in visual mode and haven't yanked the selection to the register.

To make sure there wasn't a plugin colliding with my mapping, I backed up my .vimrc and replaced it with one that only has the following contents:

```
set showcmd
map <Space> <Leader>
vmap <Leader>y "+y
```

Does one of these keys need to be escaped? Or am I doing something else wrong?

(I'm currently running Ubuntu Bash on Windows. Vim is version 7.4)

For reference, I got the idea from this article (And use the exact same command):
https://sheerun.net/2014/03/21/how-to-boost-your-vim-productivity/

Comment: After more investigation, I think perhaps this is an oddity with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. The mappings work as expected in a Vim session in Git Bash. :/

Answer (score 2):

Thankfully, the fix is pretty simple.

```
map <Space> <Leader>
```

is incorrect. The right way is

```
let mapleader=" "
```

From `:help mapleader`

```
                    *<Leader>* *mapleader*
To define a mapping which uses the "mapleader" variable, the special string
"<Leader>" can be used.  It is replaced with the string value of "mapleader".
If "mapleader" is not set or empty, a backslash is used instead.  Example: >
    :map <Leader>A  oanother line<Esc>
Works like: >
    :map \A  oanother line<Esc>
But after: >
    :let mapleader = ","
It works like: >
    :map ,A  oanother line<Esc>

Note that the value of "mapleader" is used at the moment the mapping is
defined.  Changing "mapleader" after that has no effect for already defined
mappings.
```

Comment: I originally had my leader set the way you stated; however, I ran into a thread on Reddit a few days ago (https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/2d2za5/question_about_having_spacebar_as_leader/) and changed it to the way I have now. I changed it back temporarily to verify that wasn't the culprit and unfortunately it's not.

Answer (score 1):

How to define the "leader" key is explained under `:help mapleader`. If you want to use `<Space>` as "leader" you are supposed to do:

```
let mapleader = "\<Space>"
```

Note that the "leader" key is *not* a special key at all. With `<Space>` as "leader", the two mappings below are strictly equivalent:

```
vmap <leader>y "+y
vmap <Space>y  "+y
```

Comment: I explained why I chose to set the leader the way I did. I previously had set my leader the way you have stated; however, the result is that my \ key is unused and showcmd is practically useless. I just changed it back to the way you have defined and still have the same issue.